# VSCode Snippet to replace this.setState({key: value}) with setKey(value)

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

As we convert our react codebase to hooks, it would be useful to have a snippet to convert the old setState syntax to the new useState syntax. So for example:

`this.setState({isLoading: true});`  would become `setIsLoading(true);`

I don't really understand how regex grouping and replacement works in vscode snippets even after spending a couple hours trying to get this working.

Comment: Have you got any snippet that works at least to some extent? Dven if it does not do what you need? Could you please share?

Answer (score 0):

See the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/VctEtp/1).

In a Find in file widget or to search across files:

Find: `this\.setState\(\{(.*?):\s*(.*?)\}\)`
Replace: `set\u$1($2)`

or in a snippet:

```
"setState convert": {
    "prefix": "_ssc",
    "body": [
      "${TM_SELECTED_TEXT/this\\.setState\\(\\{(.*?):\\s*(.*?)\\}\\)/set${1:/capitalize}($2)/g}",
    ],
    "description": "convert from setState"
},
```

`this\\.setState\\(\\{(.*?):\\s*(.*?)\\}\\)` this is the same as the Find regex but with a few necessary double escapes.

If you think it is necessary `(.*?):\\s*(.*?)` could be switched to
`([^:]*?):\\s*([^}]*?)` to be a little more safe, but it is probably uneccesary.

`set${1:/capitalize}($2)` the transform replace, `set` followed by capture group 1 capitalized, followed by `(` group 2 `)`.  The trailing `;` will still be there as it was never matched.

To use the snippet version you would have to select all the `this.setState({isLoading: true});` first (which you could do with the same Find regex shown above and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> with focus in the editor) and then trigger the snippet prefix.

You might find it easier to just do a Find/Replace.  If you want to save these Find/Replace regexes that can be done too.  Let me know if you want a way to do that.

Answer (score -1):

when you using react classes you have to update state with this.setState but as you mentions you changed your code base
now you have to create a const like

```
const [test, setTest] = useState(true);

//and for updating the state you have to use it like this 

const handleChange =()=>{

setTest(false);
// or you can make toggle 
setTest(!test);
}
```

Comment: I understand how to make the change, but what I am looking for is a VSCode Snippet to automate making this change in hundreds of places

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: Oh ok so regex is the answer 
Excuse me dude 
I will check it and let you know